# I want to add a border to the same styled element with a seperate css class

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors, css-specificity

I want to be able to add a border with javascript. So I thought I could do it with adding it as a seperate class . But it does not work .

```
#button1 {
    box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 0px #3dc21b;
    background-color:#44c767;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border:1px solid #18ab29;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:17px;
    padding:180px 180px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #2f6627;
    margin:200px;

    border: 30px solid black ;


}

.AddedbuttonBorder {
    border: 30px solid black ;


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using an ID and a class as CSS selectors. The ID selector has a **higher CSS specifity** than the class selector, so the `border` setting in the ID selector will have priority over the one in the class selector, regardless of their order.

To "overrule" the setting of the ID selector, you can either add `!important` to the setting in the rule that uses the class selector (`border: 30px solid black !important;`), or use a selector that combines ID *and* class, like this:

```
#button1.AddedbuttonBorder {
    border: 30px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do this with javascript you can use

```
document.getElementById('button1').classList.add('AddedbuttonBorder');
```